# Unity Dedicated Server data synchronization

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, multiplayer, data-synchronization, dedicated-server

I'm using netcode with unity's dedicated server. I want to start timer at a specific time when enemy collide with player and show this timer to all players inside server. But serverRPC cannot call in dedicated server. Dont know how to send data to server in this case.

```
private NetworkVariable<float> timerNetworkVariable = new NetworkVariable<float>(30,NetworkVariableReadPermission.Everyone,NetworkVariableWritePermission.Server);
private void Update()
{
    if (!IsServer)
    {
        Debug.Log("Client Enemy Utility");
        return;
    }
    Debug.Log("Is Server Enemy Utility");


    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    Debug.Log("Trigger Enter CLeint");
    //Debug.Log("Before server in colliisno");
    if (!IsServer) return;
    Debug.Log("Trigger Enter Server");
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {           
        //if (!waitTimer)
        //{
        //    waitTimer = true;
        //}
        //Debug.Log("Wait Timer in collision" + waitTimer);
        GetPlayers();
        startFollower = true;
    }
}
```

Is server is not working in ontrigger enter how can i send data to server to start timer

```
    public GameObject timerPanel;
public TextMeshProUGUI txtTimer;
private NetworkVariable<float> timerNewNetwork=new NetworkVariable<float>(30);
bool timeStatus = false;
bool testBool = false;
    [ServerRpc(RequireOwnership = false)]
private void TimerTestServerRpc(bool status)
{
    Debug.Log("TimerTestServerRPC");
    Timer(status);
    int val = Random.Range(1, 100);
    timerNewNetwork.Value -= val;
    TimerTestClientRpc();
}
    [ClientRpc]
private void TimerTestClientRpc()
{
    Debug.Log("Inside CLient RPC");
    if (!timerPanel.activeInHierarchy )
    {
        timerPanel.SetActive(true);
    }
    timerNewNetwork.Value -= 10;
    txtTimer.text = timerNewNetwork.Value + "";
}
    void Timer(bool status)
{
    testBool = true;
    timerNewNetwork.Value -= 10;
    Debug.Log("testBool: " + testBool);
}
    private void Update()
{
    TimerTestServerRpc(true);
}
    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
{
    if (other.CompareTag("Player"))
    {
        timeStatus = true;
    }
}
```

I updated demo script using server rpc and client rpc

Comment: what do you mean "serverRPC cannot call in dedicated server"   there is no rpccall shown here, and if the trigger is triggered the server is returning all but immediately and doing nothing, therefore it does not send to all clients because you have no clientrpc.. in its part..

Comment: also currently it looks like `OnTriggerEnter` is nested within `Update` ...? o.O Could you please post a [mcve] of your code

Comment: OnTriggerEnter is not nested i missed while uploading

Comment: I just updated code. Like this in serverRPC it just call client RPC code above client rpc didn't work

Comment: I solved it i was not uploading build after using serverRPC , whenever we change anything in serverRPC need to upload build on server